# Windows Batch File time break command

Tags: batch-file

Okay, So I am returning to programming and I have decided to start with the basic switches. No I am trying to find a switch that will allow me to stay on a certain screen for a certain amount of time. I remember is as 
*-t 30*

Problem is, when I tested it out, there was an error. I used to do these pranks through batch files that will use this command so that the... victims will be able to read what's on the window before the next line of text shows. Am I doing something wrong? I need your help.

Comment: Welcome (back?) to Stack Overflow. You're getting downvoted because while you have mentioned a chunk of code you're working on that is giving you issues, you haven't included it in your question. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32617065/edit) to include the code you've tried (code does **not** show up well in comments).

Comment: a Switch of what command? There aren't any global "switches" or parameters that would be common to all commands.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no [[man7]: SLEEP(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sleep.1.html) (I assume this is what you're looking for) equivalent on *Win*.

A common practice is to ping the localhost address; I consider that a lame workaround (*gainarie*), but it works: `ping -n <NUMBER_OF_SECONDS> 127.0.0.1`. *ping* by default sends the *ICMP* packet then waits for one second before sending (if needed, **and reply arrived**) another one; the *-n* argument specifies the number of retries, so there you have a *sleep* like behavior. Unfortunately every second, *ping* "pollutes" the console with the messages like:

> ```bat
> Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
> ```

, therefore you would want to "hide" its output.

Adding this line in your batch file, would do the trick: waits for 30 seconds (as you mentioned in your question):

```bat
ping -n 30 127.0.0.1>nul
```

Comment: Wow, I'm using _Windows_ for years and I wasn't aware of @Ghost1990' "hint". Congrats! My up-vote as well.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the `TIMEOUT>NUL /T 30 /NOBREAK` which might be more of what you were referring to with the `-t 30` you mentioned. With the `/T [time in seconds]` switch the batch file will wait how ever many seconds you want, valid range is `-1 to 99999` The `/NOBREAK` switch will ignore any keys pressed and the `>NUL` will suppress the timeout message all together.
I also wouldn't recommend using `/T -1 /NOBREAK` as "-1" will wait indefinitely similar to pause, but the batch file won't respond to any key presses.

Comment: you can avoid the redirection problem with a different syntax: `>nul timeout -t 5`

Comment: Ah, thank you for that correction @Stephan, I edited my original answer to better reflect the correct syntax